# How to export a Hive table into a CSV file where my file contains CJK words that warns illegal characters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hdfs

```
df = sol.spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable")

df.write.csv("hdfs:///user/athena_ioc/mydata.csv")
```

I am using pyspark in this case, so here i am using spark dataframe where it cannot specify encoding style, after exported something to my HDFS it shows many illegal characters where my table contains CJK words, How do i dealing with that?

after looking at my file settings it shows my original encoding is cp936, currently using spark 2.3 version which i know it is a bit old, or is there any other way to export data?

however, I have heard that trasnfer to pandas dataframe and exported to a excel file by using functions that pandas provided, but in our hadoop cluster we did not actually install that kinds of thing so it would cost more time to asking help from our maintenance therefore this would not be a good approach.

Many thanks

Comment: You can try to specify encoding (charset) of saved CSV files, e.g. ```UTF-8```.

Comment: no we cannot specify encoding of saved CSV file from spark dataframe

Comment: What is your spark version, the default character set should be UTF-8.

Comment: thanks for your comment however our version is 2.3, I've checked that i do not have this argument in my csv.write function, do you mean I should upgrade my version instead?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify its charset when saving the csv file.

```
df.write.csv("hdfs:///user/athena_ioc/mydata.csv", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: thanks for your comment however our version is 2.3, I've checked that i do not have this argument in my csv.write function, do you mean I should upgrade my version instead?

Comment: To be honest, version 2.3 is too old, and many useful new features are not available. If you are a new project, it is recommended to upgrade the version. If it is to maintain an old project, it needs to be carefully evaluated.

Comment: ok thanks anyway, I will try to call the maintenance to see if they could help the upgradation